# File Upload page coming up it is not showing the mounted folders

Tags: ubuntu, network-attached-storage, qnap

I'm using ubuntu 12 desktop and also we have QNAP NAS share in our network ,
I can mount the folder and see the files but I can't see the folder when we try to upload files onto any Internet site,
it seems the File Upload dialogue is not showing the mounted folders.
Can anyone tell me of how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mean that you mounted it using nautilus (File browser) then it will be mounted using gvfs.
In your upload dialog browse to your home directory. In there there will be a hidden directory called .gvfs which contains your mounts.